# How to create multiple instance running same time in pm2 without terminate existing process

Tags: node.js, linux, cron, scheduled-tasks, pm2

I have implemented a function in js file using nodejs application things are working fine but when I try to run every 2 minutes with the help of pm2 Every 2 mins my execution started auto but the issue is auto terminate old process.

pm2 restart pulldata.js --cron "*/2 * * * *"

pm2 start pulldata.js --cron "*/2 * * * *"

1st execution 12:00 AM

2nd execution 12:02 AM

3rd execution 12:04 AM

When start 2nd execution then 1st execution auto terminate when start 3rd execution then 2nd execution auto terminate

I want to keep running all execution until all execution done like task scheduler in windows

App built : nodejs and expressjs

Os: amazon-linux